# Page break problems with html2pdf.js

Tags: javascript, angular, html2pdf

I'm using [html2pdf.js](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf.js) in an Angular app in order to save large document (CSS formated HTML with images) to a PDF. I need to force page breaks at some points (before each field having `newPage` class). This is simplified version of my code:

```
@ViewChild('report', { static: false }) reportElement: ElementRef;

const opt = {
        filename: 'test.pdf',
        image: {type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98},
        html2canvas:  {scale: 3},
        pagebreak: {before: '.newPage', avoid: ['h2', 'h3', 'h4', '.field']},
        jsPDF: {unit: 'mm', format: 'a4', orientation: 'portrait'}
    };

html2pdf().from(this.reportElement.nativeElement).set(opt).save();
```

This works fine, but there is an issue with "soft" (non-forced) page breaks after a few pages in PDF - page breaks are being "missed" by a few pixels, getting worse at each upcoming page. The issue was reported on [package's github](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf.js/issues/227), but the proposed dirty fix is not applicable to the current package version.

Any idea how to bypass this issue?